# nginx rewrite and curly braces on variables numbers

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite variables of pattern using curly braces on the numbers to pass the 9 variable and above here

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+) /index.php?param1=${1}&param2=${2}&param3=${3]&param4=${4}&param5=${5}&param6=${6}&param7=${7}&param8=${8}&param9=${9}&param10=${10} last;
}
```

but it gives me this error message

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown "1" variable
```

Comment: Why are there curly braces there?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I asked a question about how to pass the 9 parameters limit and got this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55018255/11142047 about using curly braces

Comment: It doesn't work though. Why did you accept his answer?

Comment: @MichaelHampton i searched and found this topic https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,241016 which indicated to me that nginx allows `${}` so i suspect the problem is from me but the answer is right but didn't understand why doesn't it work for me

Comment: Any expression that contains braces must be enclosed in quotes.